# Joining two tables based on date values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hy! I would like to connect the two tables based on date, supplementing table "B" with the CUSTOMID field. I would like to ask for help in implementing the query below. I'm using oracle 11 version.

"A" table looks like...

[image]

"B" table looks like...

[image]

The expected result should be like this...

[image]

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: It's not a mistake, at that time it already had a CUSTOMID value. After 2021.03.12 17:06 every row has

Comment: Please post data as text, and explain the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could union the two tables together, will nulls for the missing columns in each:

```
select id, null as name, null as gender, null as age, "DATE", customid from a
union all
select id, name, gender, age, "DATE", null as customid from b
order by "DATE"
```

| ID | NAME | GENDER | AGE | DATE | CUSTOMID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2068121 | ST. Oliver | 1 | 18 | 2011-07-30 05:50 | *null* |
| 2068121 | Km. Oliver | 1 | 18 | 2012-01-23 11:12 | *null* |
| 2068121 | Km. Oliver | 1 | 18 | 2021-03-12 17:04 | *null* |
| 2068121 | *null* | *null* | *null* | 2021-03-12 17:06 | 10729945 |
| 2068121 | Km. Oliver | 1 | 18 | 2022-03-29 11:53 | *null* |
| 2068121 | *null* | *null* | *null* | 2022-07-25 11:01 | 10729944 |

And then fill in the gaps with an analytic query such as `last_value` to get the last non-null value seen in each column, based on the date order:

```
select id,
  last_value(name) ignore nulls over (partition by id order by "DATE") as name,
  last_value(gender) ignore nulls over (partition by id order by "DATE") as gender,
  last_value(age) ignore nulls over (partition by id order by "DATE") as age,
  "DATE",
  last_value(customid) ignore nulls over (partition by id order by "DATE") as customid
from (
  select id, null as name, null as gender, null as age, "DATE", customid from a
  union all
  select id, name, gender, age, "DATE", null as customid from b
)
order by "DATE"
```

If you don't want nulls for the first `customid` values you can coalesce those to zero:

```
coalesce(last_value(customid) ignore nulls over (partition by id order by "DATE"), 0) as customid
```

| ID | NAME | GENDER | AGE | DATE | CUSTOMID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2068121 | ST. Oliver | 1 | 18 | 2011-07-30 05:50 | 0 |
| 2068121 | Km. Oliver | 1 | 18 | 2012-01-23 11:12 | 0 |
| 2068121 | Km. Oliver | 1 | 18 | 2021-03-12 17:04 | 0 |
| 2068121 | Km. Oliver | 1 | 18 | 2021-03-12 17:06 | 10729945 |
| 2068121 | Km. Oliver | 1 | 18 | 2022-03-29 11:53 | 10729945 |
| 2068121 | Km. Oliver | 1 | 18 | 2022-07-25 11:01 | 10729944 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8842fae7e1f1cf1e5ddb6dc4e47be2a2)

Answer (score 1):

Hm, how do you plan to join those "dates" if they don't match? By **year** (that's what *does* match)?

Anyway, see if this helps.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  a (id, customid, datum) as
  3    (select 2068121, 107299445, to_date('2021.03.12 17:06', 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi') from dual union all
  4     select 2068121, 107299444, to_date('2022.07.25 11:01', 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi') from dual
  5    ),
  6  b (id, name, gender, age, datum) as
  7    (select 2068121, 'St. Oliver', 1, 18, to_date('2011.07.30 05.50', 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi') from dual union all
  8     select 2068121, 'Km. Oliver', 1, 18, to_date('2012.01.23 11.12', 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi') from dual union all
  9     select 2068121, 'Km. Oliver', 1, 18, to_date('2021.03.12 17:04', 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi') from dual union all
 10     select 2068121, 'Km. Oliver', 1, 18, to_date('2022.03.29 11:53', 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi') from dual
 11    )
```

Query begins here: first select what you already have (contents of table b):

```
 12  select b.id, b.name, b.gender, b.age, b.datum, 0 customid from b
```

Then add what's missing - joined a and b tables on ID and years from the DATUM column:

```
 13  union all
 14  select a.id, b.name, b.gender, b.age, a.datum, a.customid
 15  from a join b on a.id = b.id and trunc(a.datum, 'yyyy') = trunc(b.datum, 'yyyy')
 16  order by id, name desc, gender, datum;

        ID NAME           GENDER        AGE DATUM              CUSTOMID
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- ----------
   2068121 St. Oliver          1         18 2011.07.30 05:50          0
   2068121 Km. Oliver          1         18 2012.01.23 11:12          0
   2068121 Km. Oliver          1         18 2021.03.12 17:04          0
   2068121 Km. Oliver          1         18 2021.03.12 17:06  107299445
   2068121 Km. Oliver          1         18 2022.03.29 11:53          0
   2068121 Km. Oliver          1         18 2022.07.25 11:01  107299444

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: I was looking for a similar solution, thanks